# Javascript "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing, codeigniter-4

My JSON string looks like this

```
{"Peter":"35","Ben":"37","Joe":"43"}
```

PHP code

```
class Products{
    public function example(){
        $results = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
        echo json_encode($results);
    }
}
```

Javascript code

```
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onload = function()
{
    const obj = this.responseText;
    const obj1 = JSON.parse(obj);
    alert(obj1);

}
xhttp.open("POST", "/products/example");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send();
```

I get the error in the question when I parse it in javascript.

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: The json is valid. How do you send tis json to the parser? Are you having trubles with escape character "\" (missing or in excess)? Can you put the code here?

Comment: I'm encoding this in php using `$data=json_encode($result); print_r($data);` and sending it as a ajax response to javascript. Parsing it in javascript using `const obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText); ` No issues with "\" escape character

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mre] of both your PHP and JavaScript code.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Have you checked whether the response is sent properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending JSON from PHP you need to set a "Content-Type" Header and you cannot use `print_r`.

```
<?php
$data=json_encode($result);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $data;
```

Try looking at the response from you PHP script in the developer tools of your browser to ensure that you get the proper HTTP Content-Type header.

Comment: Thank you. This helped. I made a mistake not looking at the correct way to send HTTP responses according to the framework I'm using, which is Codeigniter 4. I set the Content-Type and sent the response using Codeigniter's reponse object and it works. Here's the code `$this->response->setContentType('application/json');
      return $this->response->setJSON($results);`

Comment: Another mistake I made was not mentioning that I'm using Codeigniter 4.